# how to filter and remove data from excel after reading through map

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to get data from excel using data provider inserting by map format. I need to filter the rows first by using test name in column 0. Below code returns a null value for the row which I do not require.

```
    String m1 = m.getName();
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() ;
    int lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    Object[][] obj = new Object[lastRowNum][1];

     for (int i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
        String tn = sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(0).toString();

        if(m1.equalsIgnoreCase(tn)){
        for (int j = 0; j < lastCellNum; j++) {`enter code here`

            datamap.put(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).toString(), sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(j).toString());
        }
    obj[i][0] = datamap;
            }

}
     return obj;`
```

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be missing important details. What is the variable "m"? Are you using some special library for accessing excel files?

Comment: m is Method passed to Dataprovider

Comment: Please make your code a minimal, verifiable and complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve